# Is there a "supported" way in RHEL/CentOS 7 to union-mount a directory tree on top of an NFS mount point?

Tags: centos, nfs, chroot, syslog, unionfs

I have an NFS share containing almost 500 chrooted (s)ftp user's home directories.

This NFS share is mounted on several FTP servers forming a highly available FTP 
cluster.

I would like to enable `syslog` logging on all the cluster nodes at the same time.

To do this, I need a `dev/log` socket in each user's home directory, and it seems that I need it to be different for each node.

Currently, only the node where the syslog daemon was first started perform any logging. I presume that is because the `dev/log` socket is in use when the other nodes try to connect to it with `socket(2)` or `listen(2)` or something like that.

So, I planned on creating an overlay directory structure on local disk on each server, containing just directories and the `dev/log` sockets.

Problem is, I'm on **CentoOS 7**, and `aufs` is not available.

**Q:** Is there a way I can have a separate `/dev/log` for each user directory (the sshd `internal-sftp` and `vsftpd` do their own chroot:ing) on each server? If so, can I do it without making a `mount --bind` for each user account, which would be my last resort?

*(Specifying the path to the log socket in vsftpd and sshd would be an elegant solution, since I tell rsyslog where to listen and can easily change that).*